# Eigenvector of a non-negative matrix

Tags: eigenvalues

A very basic question. The [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Statement) states:

> The largest eigenvalue of a matrix with non-negative entries has a corresponding eigenvector with non-negative values.

I have a matrix

```
M={{4., 25.7, 5.}, {0.25, 2.8, 0.5}, {0.2, 2.8, 2.5}}
```

Using `Eigensystem[M]` I obtain

```
{{6.57576, 1.99007, 0.734168}, {{-0.991501, -0.0793068, -0.103136}, {-0.877763,-0.0244403, 0.478471}, {-0.980885, 0.148996, -0.125161}}}
```

A negative eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue???? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One doesn't usually talk about a vector being positive or negative, although the components of may be positive, negative or a mixture of the two. Note if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $Av =\lambda v$, then for $w=kv$, $Aw = A(kv) = k(Av)k(\lambda v)=\lambda(kv)=\lambda w$; so $w$ is an eigenvector for all $k \ne 0$.  For example for $k = -1$, both $v$ and $-v$ are eigenvectors.  *Mathematica* returns one of the eigenvectors and not always the eigenvector scaled the way the user has in mind.

Answer (score 5):

You did nothing wrong. It is just that every nonzero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. `Eigensystem` may return eigenvectors that point into the "wrong" direction. Try

```
# Sign[Total[#]] &[Eigenvectors[M][[1]]]
```

This will flip the sign of the first eigenvector accordingly.

*Addressing a comment by LLlAMnYP:*

The Perron-Frobenius theorem guarantees that all the components of the first eigenvector are all nonpositive or nonnegative. Hence, if the sum of its components is `0`, the vector has already to be equal to `0`. So multiplying it by another `0` from `Sign` does not harm.

However, if the "eigenvector" of the largest eigenvalue is `0`, you have quite a lot other issues with your matrix... (I also that this cannot be obtained as result from `Eigenvalues`.)

Comment: Better use something like `((2 UnitStep[#] - 1) &)` Instead of `Sign` for the unfortunate edge case of `Total` giving a zero.

Comment: yes, I realized that and corrected :-)

Comment: If the sum of the vector's component is `0`, the vector has already to be zero: The Perron-Frobenius theorem guarantees that the all entries of the first eigenvector are all nonpositive or nonnegative. So it does not matter.

Comment: That's the brainfart that happens when not all users of MMA are mathematicians. Maybe add this to the answer? It's nice background info.